# SQL query to display the length and first 3 characters of ename column in employee table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

just as the question can we do something to get the length and first 3 characters of the employee name of one column

Please do not mark as answered or duplicate i have the test tomorrow Advance SQL so I am trying to solve some imp question.. Please answer the problem

thanks again

Comment: you should post query which you have tried.

Comment: This is dup because both Len, Left and Substring as well as how to query multiple function expressions in a single select is covered in hundreds of SO posts. If you are going for an Advanced SQL test, then this is by far assumed knowledge, it is in fact entry level. You need a codementor.io or try hackerrank.com but posting questions on SO and asking us to not dup them even when they clearly are suggests you are not ready for this test or even good at general searching for TSQL query syntax or reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LEN() or LENGTH()(in case of oracle sql) function to get the length of a column.

```
SELECT LEN(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

And you can use SUBSTRING or SUBSTR() function to get first three characters of a column.

**Ex.** SUBSTRING( string, start_position, length );

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( column_name, 1, 3 ) col_name
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: `Left(_num chars_)` is simpler for first X chars Instead of substring